# what is inbound and outbound SSL in Websphere Application server

Tags: ssl, middleware, websphere-7, outbound, inbound

inbound and outbound SSL in Websphere Application server how it works and how to differentiate which request is inbound and which request is outbound?

Answer (score 1):

An inbound SSL request is an SSL request that originates **outside** of WebSphere, where WebSphere acts as the SSL **server**.

An outbound SSL request is an SSL request that originates **inside** of WebSPhere, where WebSphere acts as the SSL **client**